# fetching data from Service and storing in Child component - Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

Here's where i use my service to get api data to child. Initially it gets the Id and other user data in console.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.commonService.userSetChange.subscribe(
      apiData => {
        this.getUserSeminar(apiData);
        this.user = apiData;
        console.log(this.user)

      });
  }
```

Then i store it with this variable.

```
user: any;
```

Add method to pass the `user` variable

```
addSeminar(): void {
    console.log(this.user.id)
    event.preventDefault();
    const seminar = {
      id: null,
      user_id: this.user.id,
      dates: null,
      name: null,
      certificate_number: null,
      edit: true,
    };
    this.userSeminars.push(seminar);
    const a = this.userSeminars.length - 1;
  }
```

But when i press the addSeminar button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="addSeminar()">Add Seminar &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

This gives me `api/users/seminar/null 500`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you strcuture your code led to the status you are in. The sreenshot is explanatory. The `undefined` log belongs to the `console.log(this.user.id)` in the method named `addSeminar(){}`. The null is a value set from your server because you sent nothing to it. However, the first part of the screenshot includes the `id:1` which is what you want to pass to the `addSeminar(){}` I guess.

You have to move the `addSeminar(){}` inside the `subscription` inside the `ngOnInit(){}` and under the  `this.user = apiData;` line you pass your parameter to the `addSeminar(){}`. If you do not like to have a fat function there, you can just add an argument to the `addSeminar(userId: string|number){}` keep it where it is and just call it in the place I pointed to above.

So your logic will be

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.commonService.userSetChange.subscribe(
      apiData => {
        this.getUserSeminar(apiData);
        this.user = apiData;
        console.log(this.user)
        this.addSeminar(this.user?.id) // see this line
      });
  }
```

PS: avoid type `any` as much as possible. You can set `unknown` it is better than `any`